# How to get the name of the url with BeautifulSoup

Tags: django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

How I can get the  name of url with BeautifulSoup. 
I've this code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
list =  soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'profileBox'})

for div in list:
    print div.a['href']

---------------------------------
<a href="/sam">sam utx</a>
-------------------------------------
```

This print the href("/sam") but I need is the url's name (sam utx).
How I can make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the `text` inside the `div` itself with this :

```
div.a.string
```

You can read more about this [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).